# More natural way of storing a 2 index object?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have lots of data which is indexed with two indexes. Currently I am storing things as nested dictionaries like

```
{1000: {3: 1.0, 4: 2.0}, 1001: {3: 3.0, 4: 4.0} , 1002: {3: 5.0, 4: 0.0}}
```

So I can access data with `mydata[1000][4]`. I have this nested dictionary in a wrapper class which lets me access all elements with the second index `mydata.get(second=4)` to give [`2.0, 4.0, 0.0]`

Nested dictionaries work but are pretty messy IMO. I recently started building these structures with ~100,000 entries and the inital building of nested dictionaries has proven to be really slow.

Is there a more natural or more pythonic way of having data with two indecies? Does it help if the inner index is always the same set?

Comment: How about indexing by a pair? ie: {(1000,3) : 1.0, (1000,4) : 2.0}

Comment: Depending on how "tabular" your data is, you could look at [`numpy`](http://numpy.scipy.org/) and/or  [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: What is "natural" (and what is efficient) depends on the access pattern: what you use to look up values, and what kind of values you expect to get from that.

Comment: If the inner keys are always 3 and 4, you can just get rid of them and replace the inner dictionaries with 2-tuples.

Comment: @BrenBarn I have looked into pandas for this but ran into problems. It works great for the case I posted up there, but seems to have trouble if I want the data to not be simple numbers like in my example. I should have been clear, I just used floats as an example of the internal data.

Comment: it might be more useful to show your code for building the nested dictionaries so that people can see how you're using them

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can achieve this by abusing a bit slices:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class MyDict:
    def __init__ (self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        if isinstance (key, int):
            return [_ for _ in self.d [key].values () ]
        if isinstance (key, slice):
            if key.start == None:
                return [v for s in (d.items () for d in self.d.values () ) for k, v in s if k == key.stop]
            if key.stop == None:
                return [_ for _ in self.d [key.start].values () ]
            return self.d [key.start] [key.stop]
        [] [key]

d = {1000: {3: 1.0, 4: 2.0}, 1001: {3: 3.0, 4: 4.0} , 1002: {3: 5.0, 4: 0.0}}
d = MyDict (d)

print (d [1000] )
print (d [1000:] )
print (d [:4] )
print (d [1001:4] )
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting use of slices. I will use that for sure. That doesn't solve the problem that building thousands of nested dictionaries turns out to be slow, but it is a much nicer way of accessing the data than I have been doing.